# find which number in a list sum up to a certain number but with negative and decimals

Tags: python

I have a quite big listed number that includes negatives, 2nd placed decimal numbers. For example, `(10348.94, -984.23, 9429.92)`. I want to find the sum of a number that adds up from one in one of the list. Also the number in the list can be repeated, and the given sum can be negative.

Here is what I got so far, the repetition and the decimal seems to work but when I try to do a negative numbers both in the list and the given sum it wouldn't work.

```
def Find(goal, VarienceNum):
    variance = [[Listed] for Listed in VarienceNum]
    newList = []
    result = []

    while variance:
        for holder in variance:
            s = sum(holder)
            for Listed in VarienceNum:
                if Listed >= holder[-1]:
                    if s + Listed < goal:
                        newList.append(holder + [Listed])
                    elif s + Listed == goal:
                        result.append(holder + [Listed])
        variance = newList
        newList = []
    return result
goal=float(input("please enter your goal: "))
VarienceNum=list(map(float,input("please enter the list: ").split()))
print(Find(goal,VarienceNum))
```

[here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ4tK.png)

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Is there a limit on how many numbers can be used to reach the sum? If not you're probably best looking at all subsets of the list (`O(2 ^ n)`) and filtering for those subsets which sum to the correct number

Comment: no there aren't any limits on how many times u can use to reach the sum, Also I'm not sure how to filter out all the zero if you know how to it would be great if you show me. Thanks for the reply I really appreciated it.

Comment: @Matthew let me know if you've had any issues with my answer

Answer (score 2):

Get all subsets of the list, check the sum of each subset, and when that sum finally matches the target value return that subset!

```
def inc_bool_array(arr, ind=0):
    
    '''
    Increments an array of booleans; some examples:
    [ 0, 0, 0 ] -> [ 1, 0, 0 ]
    [ 1, 0, 0 ] -> [ 1, 1, 0 ]
    [ 1, 1, 0 ] -> [ 0, 0, 1 ]
    [ 0, 0, 1 ] -> [ 1, 0, 1 ]
    .
    .
    .
    '''

    if (ind >= len(arr)): return;
    
    if (arr[ind] == 0):
        arr[ind] = 1;
    else:
        arr[ind] = 0;
        inc_bool_array(arr, ind + 1);

def find_subset_sum(target, arr):
    
    size = len(arr);
    pick = [ 0 for n in arr ];
    num_subsets = 2 ** size;
    
    '''
    Loop through every possible subset until we find one such that
    `sum(subset) == target`
    '''
    for n in range(num_subsets):
        
        ''' Subset is determined by the current boolean values in `pick` '''
        subset = [ arr[ind] for ind in range(size) if pick[ind] == 1 ];
        
        if sum(subset) == target: return subset;
        
        ''' Update `pick` to the next set of booleans '''
        inc_bool_array(pick);
    
    return None;

print(find_subset_sum(3, [ 1, 2, 3 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(5, [ 1, 2, 3 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(6, [ 1, 2, 3 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(7, [ 1, 2, 3 ]));

print(find_subset_sum(3, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(4, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(5, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(6, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(7, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(8, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(12, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
print(find_subset_sum(13, [ -1, 5, 8 ]));
```

The hard part here is getting all possible subsets of the list. Getting all subsets is a matter of choosing "include" or "exclude" for every item in the list (2 options per element results in `2^n` possible choices, and `2^n` possible subsets).

In order to enumerate all these choices I use a simple array called `pick` which is composed of boolean values; one boolean value for each value in the source array. Each boolean represents an include/exclude choice for its corresponding value in the source array. The array starts full of only `0`, representing the choice of "exclude" for each item. Then a function called `inc_bool_array` is used to update `pick` to the next set of values. This means pick will take on these values over time:

```
Step 1: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 2: [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 3: [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 4: [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 5: [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 6: [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 7: [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 8: [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ... ]
Step 9: [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ... ]
.
.
.
```

Gradually every possible combination of `0`s and `1`s will occur. Then `pick` is used to generate a subset which only contains values corresponding to a `1`, simply using a generator with an `if` condition:

```
subset = [ arr[ind] for ind in range(len(arr)) if pick[ind] == 1 ]
```